# React setState hook not working with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. The idea is to create a simple loading for a mock component

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  function mockLoading () {
    setLoading(true)
    console.log('1', loading)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log('2', loading)
    }, 3000)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    mockLoading()
  }, []);
```

But for some reason, setLoading is not working.
Console.log 1 and 2 both are false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare  your `handler` inside `useEffect` and log outside

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
      function mockLoading () {
         setLoading(true)
         console.log('1', loading)
         setTimeout(() => {
         setLoading(false)
         console.log('2', loading)
       }, 3000)
  }
    mockLoading()
  }, []);

  console.log(loading)
```

Also, you should clean your `timeout` on `unmount`

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const timeout = setTimeout(() =>{}, 0)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
},[])
```

Answer (score 12):

A couple of things. One issue is that when you set the state, the state does not immediately update. So your first console.log will see the old state. Not only that, but when your effect is called and `mockLoading` is called, it will only see the instance of state that existed at the time it was called. So any changes to the variable will never be seen by `mockLoading`. This is why effects have dependencies. That way when a dependency updates, you'll see it. But I don't think having a dependency here will help given how your code is structured. I'm not 100% clear on your final goal, but to accomplish what you want based on the code you submitted, you'll want to `useRef` instead of `useState`. `useRef` gives you an object who's value is always current. See:

```js
const loadingRef = useRef(false)

function mockLoading () {
    loadingRef.current = true;
    console.log('1', loadingRef.current)
    setTimeout(() => {
        loadingRef.current = false;
      console.log('2', loadingRef.current)
    }, 3000)
}

useEffect(() => {
    mockLoading()
}, []);
```

Using refs is generally frowned upon unless you absolutely need it. Try to refactor your code to have a dependency on `loading` in your `useEffect` call. Though keep in mind you may end up with an infinite loop if your `mockLoading` always updates `loading` when it's called. Try to only update `loading` if it's not already set to the value you want. If your end goal is to just update `loading` after 3 seconds, try this:

```js
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(true);
    },3000);
},[]);

return <span>{loading ? 'Loading is true!' : 'Loading is false!'}</span>;
```

If you want to inspect the value of loading without rendering it, then you'll need another `useEffect` with a dependency on `loading`:

```js
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(true);
    },3000);
},[]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loading);
},[loading]);

return <span>{loading ? 'Loading is true!' : 'Loading is false!'}</span>;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. The idea is to create a fake loading like when you call an api

Answer (score 3):

Setting state in React is async, so you won't see the changes to the state straight after you made them. To track state changes you need to use the effect hook:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

function mockLoading() {
  setLoading(true);
  console.log("1", loading);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
    console.log("2", loading);
  }, 3000);
}

useEffect(() => {
  mockLoading();
}, []);

// Display the current loading state
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("loading", loading);
}, [loading]);
```